# Redirect old domain with query paramaters

Tags: htaccess, apache

Apologies if this is the wrong place, but I have a WordPress site and I need to bulk redirect an old domain with various query paramaters to a new URL...

The old domain is: `www.mysite.com/newspage.asp?m=4&y=2015`

and I need that URL, as well as that URL with different query paramaters to go to: `mysite.com/news`.

I've looked over various parts of the Internet but can't seem to find anything that works, so any help would be great!

Also, I would like to do this via the `.htaccess` file...

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: Voted to clause as this is not [specific to WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) or [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) will be a better place to ask. And if you do so, please provide what you already tried

Comment: Read up on RewriteRules. https://perishablepress.com/redirect-query-string-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

> The old domain is: `www.example.com/newspage.asp?m=4&y=2015`
>
> and I need that URL, as well as that URL with different query paramaters to go to: `example.com/news`.

So, you are also changing the host with this redirect (www subdomain to bare domain)? Otherwise, it just looks like you can ignore the query string. This is relatively trivial to do with mod_rewrite. The following directives would need to go near the top of your `.htaccess` file, *before* the WordPress front controller.

```
 RewriteRule ^newspage\.asp$ http://example.com/news? [R=301,L]
```

This matches *any* query string.

The `?` on the end of the `RewriteRule` *substitution* removes the query string from the request. Otherwise, it gets passed through to the target URL. Alternatively, on Apache 2.4+, you can use the `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag instead.